# Layout with ListView, keyboard push the whole layout out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

this question has been asked a couple of time but I can't make my layout works correctly anyway.
My view is a chat view, one ListView and an EditText and a send button.

What I want is simple, just push up my EditText + send button when keyboard is show. And don't push up the rest of the layout.

The actual layout :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
  <include
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar"
      />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_chat"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
      android:divider="#00000000"
      android:listSelector="#00000000"
      android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar"
      ></ListView>
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@drawable/chat_box"
      >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/chatText"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textFieldColor"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_grey600_36dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And what I tried in the Manifest :

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

=> Push my EditText well but also the rest of my layout out of the screen including the toolbar.

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

=> Push nothing. The EditText stay behind the keyboard

Does someone see from where the problem comes ? Thank's

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:padding="5sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/send_now"
            android:id="@+id/send_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What about the toolbar ? it change nothing

Comment: i was using ActionBarActivity back then.